# How to capture a still image with AVFoundation and display the image in another view controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, avfoundation, segue

**GOAL:** I am using AVFoundation to a create custom camera that acts similar to Facebook, Instagram, and Snapchats camera image capturing sequence.

Below is my controller with the ideal UX:

- User presses plus sign button
- app segues/transitions to custom camera View Controller using AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, shown as purple area
- User presses **Take button** to capture image
- app segues to a still/image View controller of the picture they just took so the user can edit or whatever else must happen
- user presses **Use button**
- app saves the image and pops to the root ViewController

[Here is my Swift Storyboard of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c3aV.png)

**PROBLEM:** I am able to get a live video feed to using AVCapturePreviewLayer however once I capture my picture I am unable to transfer the captured UIImage to the second ViewController. I am using a segue that I trigger at the end captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection completion callback.

Here is the MasterViewController?

```
class AddPhotoViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var previewLayerView: UIView!


var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var imageDetail: UIImage?


@IBAction func cancelCameraBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}



@IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {


        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in

            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

                self.imageDetail = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("captureSessionDetailSegue", sender: self)
            }
        })
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    captureSession!.stopRunning()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // display properties
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }

    if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession!.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)


            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait



            previewLayerView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            //previewLayerView.layer.removeAllAnimations()


            captureSession!.startRunning()
        }
    }

}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer!.frame = previewLayerView.bounds
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    //if segue.identifier == "captureSessionDetailSegue" {

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! CaptureSessionDetailViewController
    destination.capturedImage.image = self.imageDetail

    // returns nil propertyfrom here
    //destination.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    //}
}


}
```

Here is the DetailViewController?

```
class CaptureSessionDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var capturedImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

My current code yields **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. I think its because of my prepareForSegue method setting something that is not present yet but I do not know how to get the image to the desired DetailViewController.

How can I achieve my desired results?

Comment: where is your capture photo  method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign image Directly like:

```
destination.capturedImage.image = self.imageDetail
```

But declare another instance which will hold your image into `CaptureSessionDetailViewController` like shown below:

```
var capturedImageRef = UIImage()
```

Now you can assign image to `CaptureSessionDetailViewController` from `AddPhotoViewController` this way into your `Segue` method:

```
destination.capturedImageRef = self.imageDetail
```

Now in `viewDidLoad` of `CaptureSessionDetailViewController` you can assign that image to `imageView`:

```
capturedImage.image = capturedImageRef
```

Comment: The additions are still causing the 

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I want to say its because the segue is being called before the data has been assigned to the image reference and made available.

Comment: make sure that `self.imageDetail` is not nil while performing segue operation.

Comment: can you share any sample project?

Comment: I tried your method again and this was actually the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My solution used design patterns from the above user (Dharmesh Kheni) and the [DBCamera custom camera github](https://github.com/danielebogo/DBCamera).

In `AddPhotoViewController`

```
    @IBAction func takePhotoBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in

            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)

                // Setup class variable --> imgMetaData: NSData!
                // Assign and transport to destination ViewController
                self.imgMetaData = imageData

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("captureSessionDetailSegue", sender: self)
            }
        })
    }
}
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "captureSessionDetailSegue" {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! CaptureSessionDetailViewController

        destination.capturedImageMetaData = self.imgMetaData


    }
}
```

In `CaptureSessionDetailViewController`

```
class CaptureSessionDetailViewController: UIViewController {


var capturedImageMetaData: NSData!


@IBOutlet var capturedImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(capturedImageMetaData)
    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

    let img = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)


    capturedImage.image = img


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Image data from the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` was assign to class variable `imgMetaData: NSData!` within the `AddPhotoViewController`. The data was transferred with `prepareForSegue` to the destination view controller `CaptureSessionDetailViewController` and stored in `capturedImageMEtaData: NSData!`. Then the data was converted to `UIImage` in the `viewDidLoad` method.